# Rendering objects in collection one by one

Tags: python, rendering, objects, collections

To start, this is my first script in Blender so be kind please :)

What I try to achieve is to render all the objects I've got in a specific collection.

The script I've made seems to work but Blender crashes after the second image.

```
import bpy, os

os.system("cls")

def multi_render():

    scene = bpy.data.scenes

    collection = bpy.data.collections['My_collection']
    imagePath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath

    name = collection.name + "_"

    # Hiding (render and viewport) all objects in collection
    for obj in collection.all_objects:
        obj.hide_render = True
        obj.hide_viewport = True

    #Rendering
    for obj in collection.all_objects:

        #Unhide object to render
        obj.hide_render = False

        fullPath = imagePath + obj.name + ".jpg"

        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fullPath
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

        #Hide rendered object
        obj.hide_render = True

multi_render()
```

I'm new to scripting, probably missed something.

Thanks in advance for helping me